# Send a binary Buffer to client through http.ServerResponse in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, binary

I have a binary data(like image file) in Buffer object(not file), and want to serve the raw binary data to client through http.ServerResponse.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Could you please make clear why the question is downvoted, if possible ?

Comment: I don't know why it is downvoted, but I was looking through Node's Response.js source and API, and I logged its keys, but I could not find a write method. What is the write method? Where did you learn of it?

Comment: The method is well documented in [node js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) you can also find an explanation in the [classic w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/obj_http_serverresponse.asp)

Answer (score 37):

I managed to find out the answer. Just add "binary" encoding to both write() and end().

```
    res.write(buffer,'binary');
    res.end(null, 'binary');
```

Note that both "write" and "end" function requires the 'binary' encoding specified. Otherwise, the buffer is encoded as UTF-8.
(So, JPEG header "ff d8 ff e0" will be "c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0"...)

Answer (score 0):

Using Axios for fetch the Binary data and send as Image

```
app.get(url, async (req, res) => {
  let { thread, blob } = req.params;
  try {
    let { data, body, headers } = await axios.get(...);
    res.end(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("e", e);
    res.send("error");
  }
});
```