# Displaying an image from a Postgresql database in the browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api

I have stored an image in a postgresql database and i have accessed that picture from database with Node.js and displayed it on the browser with

```
res.send(`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}" />`);
```

but now i have set up a miniature REST API that only serves that picture but i do not know where to go about it, i have tried sending the whole encoded data like (src = "data:image/png;base64,......)) and then creating an IMG element and making the src of that image with that data. i am in the dark here, any help would be appreciated

```
app.get('/', async(req,res) => {
  try {
    const query = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM picture");
    console.log(query.rows)
    const buff = query.rows;
    const b64 = buff[0].image.toString('base64');
    const src = "data:image/png;base64,"+b64;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'image/png');
    res.send(src);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }

})
```

Comment: A base-64 encode Data URI is _not_ of `Content-type: image/png`. After this header, you need to send the _actual_ binary image data.

Comment: how? what kind of header should i use?

Comment: That one. But you should not send data after it, that is something different. (Trying to serve a data URI over HTTP directly makes little sense.)

Comment: so how do i display the picture from the database to my app?

Comment: You need to output the _raw_ binary image data you have stored in your database after this header, and not something "encoded" any other way.

Comment: but the problem is when i interact with the database using node, i get the data as a buffer. so can i send the binary data as the buffer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391134/send-a-binary-buffer-to-client-through-http-serverresponse-in-node-js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244612/discussion-between-falconcode-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with a lot of good guys from here, i found the problem. I did not need to convert image data from the database to base64 format, i can directly serve the image as it's original binary format but have to indicate this header:

```
res.setHeader('Content-type:', 'image/jpg');
```

and if i need to use that image in my html i just do this:

```
<img src="/path to api /" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your route name to `/picture`, and after You can directly put the url of your route in your html img tag src like `<img src='/picture'>`

Replace here the img string with your fetched string from DB:
[take a look here for working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-herschel-9uj2zw?file=/app.js)

```
app.get("/picture", async (req, res) => {
  let img =
    "data:image/png;base64,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";
  img = Buffer.from(img.split(",")[1], "base64");
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Content-Length": img.length
  });
  res.end(img);
});
```

Comment: <img src='http://localhost:3000/picture'> i did that, it still does not work and yes i changed the url to app.get('/picture/', ....).

Comment: Take a look once again I edited my answer to be more explicit, you have a problem in how you serve your image